# Get values from XML tags with dynamically specified data fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, select

I have 2 tables:

Table1 has a list of XML tag names that I want to extract from an XML field. I simulate this by running this query

`SELECT 
'CLIENT'
UNION SELECT
'FEE'
UNION SELECT
'ADDRESS'`

This results in a single column with 3 rows in it, the names of which will be used to extract corresponding data from XML tags.

The second table has a column called `ClientData`, it is in XML format and it has thousands of rows of data. My task is to extract values from XML tags specified in Table1, in this case I want values from 3 xml tags: Client, FEE and ADDRESS.

So, if  the XML is this

```
<XML>
    <CLIENT>some client</CLIENT>
    <FEE>some fee</FEE>
    <ADDRESS>some address</ADDRESS>
 </XML>
```

After running a query I should get this:

`Client, FEE, ADDRESS`

`some client, some fee, some address`

Right now i have a query:

`SELECT 
 coalesce(Cast(ClientData as xml).value('(/XML/CLIENT)[1]', 'varchar(max)'), ''),
 coalesce(Cast(ClientData as xml).value('(/XML/FEE)[1]', 'varchar(max)'), ''),
 coalesce(Cast(ClientData as xml).value('(/XML/ADDRESS)[1]', 'varchar(max)'), '')
FROM dbo.Table2 WITH(NOLOCK)`

This gives me the necessary result, however it is not dynamic. Meaning, if I want to include a 4th xml value, lets say, `PHONE`, I would need to add `coalesce(Cast(ClientData as xml).value('(/XML/PHONE)[1]', 'varchar(max)'), '')` to the SELECT

My question is, 
How do I make my query dynamic so that instead of hardcoding tag names that I want to extract from XML in Table2 I would use Tabl1 as a source of tag names to extract?

I hope my explanation was good enough :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using `DYNAMIC SQL`

The TagsTable should have all the possible Tags

we can then construct `SQL` using the tag names and execute it

```
create table TagsTable
(  tagName varchar(256)
)

insert into TagsTable values ('CLIENT')
insert into TagsTable values ('FEE')
insert into TagsTable values ('ADDRESS')

declare @query nvarchar(max)

SELECT @query = STUFF((select  ',' + 'coalesce(Cast(ClientData as xml).value(''(/XML/' 
                                   + tagName + ')[1]'', ''varchar(max)''), '''') as ' + tagName +' '
FROM TagsTable
FOR XML PATH ('') ), 1,1,'')


SET @query = 'SELECT ' +  @query + 'FROM dbo.Table2 WITH(NOLOCK)'
select @query

exec sp_executesql @query
```