# SQL XML parsing using a attribute value supplied by another field in the same row

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xml-parsing, webserver

**Context:** I'm scraping some XML form descriptions from a Web Services table in hopes of using that name to identify what the user has inputted as response. Since this description changes for each step (row) of the process and each product I want something that can evaluate dynamically.

**What I tried:** The following was quite useful but it returns a dynamic attribute query result in it's own field ans using a coalesce to reduce the results as one field would lead to it's own complications: [Get values from XML tags with dynamically specified data fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26287839/get-values-from-xml-tags-with-dynamically-specified-data-fields)

**Current Attempt:**
I'm using the following code to generate the attribute name that I will use in the next step to query the attribute's value:

```
case when left([Return], 5) = '<?xml' 
    then lower(cast([Return] as xml).value('(/response/form/*/@name)[1]','varchar(30)')) 
    else '' 
    end as [FormRequest]
```

And as part of step 2 I have used the STUFF function to try and make the row-level query possible

```
case when len(FormRequest)>0
    then stuff( ',' + 'cast([tmpFormResponse] as xml).value(''(/wrapper/@' + [FormRequest] + ')[1]'',''varchar(max)'')', 1, 1, '') 
    else '' 
    end as [FormResponse]
```

Instead of seeing 1 returned as my FormReponse feild value for the submit attribute (please see in yellow below) it's returning the query text -- cast([tmpFormResponse] as xml).value('(/wrapper/@submit)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJkH9.png)','varchar(max)') -- instead (that which should be queried).
[image: query result]

How should I action the value method so that I can dynamically strip out the response per row of XML data in tmpFormResponse based on the field value in the FormRequest field?

Thanx

Comment: This is - at least for me - totally unclear... Please add some realisitc (but reduced!) sample data and the expected output.

Comment: Thanx for the response @Shnugo. Your frustration might be shared with the rest. Ended up hacking the problem by using two old faithfuls, PATINDEX and CHARINDEX.

Comment: My magic crystal ball tells me, that you might be looking for something like `local-name(.)=sql:variable["@somevariable"]`. if you want to read an element from an XML where the element's name is know in a variable, you can iterated the nodes / attributes to pick the one with this name. I'd not recommend to query an XML with string methods...

Comment: AHhhh...I've seen `local-name(.)=sql:variable["@somevariable"]` mentioned on another thread...that might be the solution, I'll need to test it.

Comment: With regards to the XML parsing using string methods, I actually transformed an "&" separated list of values (e.g. `attribute1=value1&attribute2=value2&attribute3&value3`) into XML in the hopes of making it easier to return the values of interest. So it's basically just undoing that transformation step.

Comment: You can check my answer... Sounds like an XY-problem. It would help to describe your problem providing a MCVE (with DDL and DML), with sample data and expected output. Nobody can guess your needs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this out:

```sql
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<root>
<SomeAttributes a="a" b="b" c="c"/>
<SomeAttributes a="aa" b="bb" c="cc"/>
</root>';

DECLARE @localName NVARCHAR(100)='b';

SELECT sa.value(N'(./@*[local-name()=sql:variable("@localName")])[1]','nvarchar(max)')
FROM @xml.nodes(N'/root/SomeAttributes') AS A(sa)
```

Comment: Shnugo, you sir, are my hero. I tweaked it based on one of your answers on another posting and used the `sql:column` formulation because I needed the value held in another field row
`cast([tmpFormResponse] as xml).value('(/wrapper/@*[local-name()=sql:column("FormRequest")])[1]','varchar(max)')`

Comment: @CharlesCrous glad to help you! Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

Ended up hacking up a solution to the problem by using PATINDEX and CHARINDEX to look for the value in the [FormRequest] field in the he tmpFormResponse field.